# Need to resolve three different netowrk

Tags: linux-networking

I have three networks viz 10.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/18 and 192.16.0.1/24. I have a watchguard router,which has Lan IPs, 10.0.0.4,172.16.0.1 and 192.168.0.1 and routing enabled for these networks in this router.Currently I have a DNS server (Bind) in 10.0.0.0 network, and I would like to serve the existing DNS server for other network also. Please explain how to make this setup, do i need to put DNS server for each network ?

Bascially I need to resolve each network machines from other networks.

Hope i explain my setup, if needed i will give further details

Answer (score 2):

You have said you have routing enabled, is there any firewall rules in place. If so, would you list them?

As far as DNS I will assume you will allow UDP port 53 between all three networks. If that is the case you just need to create forward and reverse lookup zones for all of your networks and then point your clients to your DNS server. Unless you want to isolate the networks, you don't need a DNS host on each network.   Although I would create a second DNS server for fault tolerance that is synchronized the your primary DNS and located on the same network.